# Linq2Xml - how to get nodes and childnodes related

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have xml like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <supplyCrew xmlns="http://site.ddf.com">
     <login>
        <login>XXXX</login>
        <password>XXXX</password>
     </login>
     <flightInformation>
        <flights>
           <item>
              <arrivalDateTime>2010-11-08T22:48:00.000Z</arrivalDateTime>
              <arrivingCity>ORD</arrivingCity>
              <crewMembers>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>020040</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>Y</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>N</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>09000</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>N</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>Y</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
              </crewMembers>
           </item>
           <item>
              <arrivalDateTime>2010-11-08T20:29:00.000Z</arrivalDateTime>
              <arrivingCity>JFK</arrivingCity>
              <crewMembers>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>0538</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>Y</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>N</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>097790</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>N</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>Y</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
              </crewMembers>
           </item>
        </flights>
     </flightInformation>
  </supplyCrew>
```

This code gets only the first item  "  and " and then generate a exception 'System.NullReferenceException'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{ 

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        XElement doc = XElement.Load("U:/Crew.xml");
        XNamespace e = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        XNamespace s = "http://site.ddf.com";

                   var flights = doc.Elements(e + "Body")
        .Elements(s + "supplyCrew")
        .Elements(s + "flightInformation")
        .Elements(s + "flights")
        .Elements(s + "item")
        .Select(
        flight_item => new
        {
            //Anonymous Type
            arrivalDateTime = flight_item.Element(s + "arrivalDateTime").Value,
            arrivingCity = flight_item.Element(s + "arrivingCity").Value,
            crewmember = flight_item.Elements(s + "crewMembers").Elements(s + "item"),

        }
        );


        int index = 1;
        foreach (var flight_item in flights)
        {

            Console.Write('\n'+"New flight item:"+'\n');
            Console.Write('\t'+flight_item.arrivalDateTime + '\n');
            Console.Write('\t'+flight_item.arrivingCity + '\n');

            foreach (var item in flight_item.crewmember)
            {
                var employeeId = item;//crewmember.Elements(s + "item").Elements("employeeId");
                Console.Write("\t  "+employeeId);
                Console.Write('\n');
                //index++;
            }

        }
```

The idea is to get item.arrivalDateTime and item.arrivingCity and its  crewMembers.item.employeeId for all the rows. However I do not know how to get the childnodes using linq...us occrring a exception if when try employeeId = x.Element(s + "employeeId").Value....

Result should be something like this:

> 2010-11-08T22:48:00.000Z; ORD; 020040
>
> 2010-11-08T22:48:00.000Z; ORD; 09000
>
> 2010-11-08T20:29:00.000Z; JFK; 0538
>
> 2010-11-08T20:29:00.000Z; JFK; 097790

Comment: *Where* is it getting the exception? I suspect it's just a missing value, but it's a lot easier for you to point that out than for us to put together a complete program and run it...

Comment: Yes, but *where exactly* in the foreach? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @Jon Skeet...Sorry about that Jon....now the full code and xml...the exception is occurring into the "x =>" new block

Comment: For all of our sakes, if this code is going into an air traffic control system please check that your XElements are not null before calling .Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

we just need to replace that foreach for :

```
        foreach (var flight_item in l_flights)
        {

            Console.Write('\n'+"New flight item:"+'\n');
            Console.Write('\t'+flight_item.arrivalDateTime + '\n');
            Console.Write('\t'+flight_item.arrivingCity + '\n');

            foreach (var item in flight_item.crewmember)
            {
                var employeeId = item.Element(s + "employeeId").Value;
                var isDepositor = item.Element(s + "isDepositor").Value;
                var isTransmitter = item.Element(s + "isTransmitter").Value;

                Console.Write("\t  " + employeeId + "\n");
                Console.Write("\t  " + isDepositor + "\n");
                Console.Write("\t  " + isTransmitter + "\n");

            }

        }
```

Thank you guys....

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your use of `Descendants`. You're asking for all `item` descendants of `flights` elements - which means it will include this:

```
<item>
   <employeeId>020040</employeeId>
   <isDepositor>Y</isDepositor>
   <isTransmitter>N</isTransmitter>
</item>
```

That clearly doesn't have an `arrivalDateTime` element, hence the problem.

Replacing every call of `Descendants` to `Elements` in your sample code fixes the problem... although you're still going to fail if the actual document doesn't have all of the expected data.

Comment: ..Thanks....Do you think If I use  "XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//s:crewMembers/s:item", nsm);" would it solve the problem of Descendants?

Comment: @BiancaFonseca: You could do that - but given how easy it is to just switch to using `Elements`, that's what I'd do. I'm not a great fan of XPath when it's so easy to avoid it with LINQ to XML... especially when it comes to namespaces.

Comment: yes..it runs with Elements, but fail when I try to get a childnode "employeeId = x.Element(s + "employeeId").Value"

Comment: @BiancaFonseca: You haven't given us nearly enough context to help diagnose that - it will work fine if `x` is an `item` element within a `crewMembers` element, but you haven't said what `x` is at all...